# How to toggle individual row details using Bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using `bootstrap-vue` [table](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table) for a project and got stuck on a problem with no documentation.

How can I toggle 1 row details at the time?

There is a complete table example here of a table with data on [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#complete-example)

Comment: You ask a question and link the answer, which would be in the complete example. What is it specifically you don't understand about the example?

Comment: @Hiws  show me the answer on the link, please :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the `v-model` and setting it to a different array, as the `v-model` on `b-table` returns the currently shown items, after filtering and pagination. Making it more performance friendly as you're limiting the amount of items you gotta loop through to close.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Povl', age: 26, gender: 'Male', secret: 'I love kittens' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Charlie', age: 9, gender: 'Female', secret: 'I love cupcakes' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Max', age: 71, gender: 'Male', secret: 'I love puppies' }
        ],
        currentItems: [],
        fields: [
          { key: 'name' }, { key: 'age' }, { key: 'gender' }, { key: 'actions' }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      //finds a specific item based on the provided ID and toggles details on that item
      toggleDetails(row) {
        if(row._showDetails){
          this.$set(row, '_showDetails', false)
        }else{
          this.currentItems.forEach(item => {
            this.$set(item, '_showDetails', false)
          })

          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$set(row, '_showDetails', true)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-container class='pt-3'>
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" v-model="currentItems" bordered fixed>
      <template v-slot:cell(actions)="{ detailsShowing, item }" >
        <!-- Use the built in method from the scoped data to toggle the row details -->
        <b-btn @click="toggleDetails(item)">{{ detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} secret</b-btn>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:row-details="{ item }">
        <b-card>
          {{ item.secret }}
        </b-card>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

Comment: see now my issue is I can toggle multiple rows at the same time, that's not what I want. I want to toggle 1 row at the time... open row B, close row A

Comment: You can do that in the code i pasted? You can toggle each row by clicking the button in each row. and the 3rd button at the top toggle a specific row based on `id` in this case

Comment: @Jonathan I've edited the answer to do what i think you want. Otherwise edit your question to go further in depth explaining exactly what it is you want, otherwise people can't help you.

Comment: @Hiws Why not just use `row.toggleDetails()` instead of `this.$set(...)`? Am i missing something?

Comment: @qqmber36 Because that function isn't exposed in the `toggleDetails` function as it is set up in the snippet. You would have to send it over from the slot data to the method to use it. It was simpler to just set `_showDetails` directly on the item.

Answer (score 2):

@Hiws answer only works for me when I add `@row-clicked` listener to `b-table`.

I couldn't get it to work if is clicked through the actions slot, just like the example given. I changed the `if` condition as it was returning me an `undefined` which caused the logic to only run the `else` part

```
toggleDetails(row) {
  if (row.detailsShowing) {
    row.toggleDetails()
  } else {
    this.currentItems.forEach(item => {
      this.$set(item, '_showDetails', false)
    })
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      row.toggleDetails()
    })
  }
}
```